# SQL Server database updating automatically with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a schema table in my database. Sometimes, the values in one column (which contains json strings) are updating automatically with special characters like `}`, `}}` or some Chinese characters. Has anyone faced the same issue before? If yes can you help?

[image]

this is a screenshot of my table.The last column of Two,three rows are updating with special characters.

Comment: tags and title database doesn't match

Comment: providing sample data will be helpful